# navigating to a specific section of another page with React Link tag

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink, navigation

let's say I have a button called 'contact me' on the header.
when I click on the button it will redirect me to the contact section of the home page even though I am on the other page.

how will I set this up with react Link tag? i try to use it like this

```
 <Link to="/#contactsec" > contact Me <Link>
```

it redirects me to the home page but I do not go to the contactsec of the home page.

how I can do this.

Comment: Try this  `<Link to="/contactsec" > contact Me <Link>` Can you please share your routing code?

Answer (score 2):

Use a useEffect hook to grab the identifier (the portion of the URL after the '#' symbol), locate an element with the same ID on the page, and then smoothly scroll to it if it exists.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const href = window.location.href.substring(
    window.location.href.lastIndexOf('#') + 1
  );
  const element = document.getElementById(href);
  if (element) {
    element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
  }
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 const navigate = useNavigate();
 const navigateToContact = () => {
 navigate("/");
 setTimeout(() => {
  const contactSection = document.getElementById("contact");
  if (contactSection) {
    contactSection.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
  }
}, 100); // Delay for smoother scroll
```

};

//button

```
<button onClick={navigateToContact}>Contact us</button>
```

By using this approach, when the button is clicked, it will redirect to the home page and smoothly scroll to the section with the ID "contact".

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it'll fit the user experience you want, but a solution is to open it in another tab, like this

`<Link to="/#contactsec" target="_blank" > contact Me <Link>`